# Трансформация web.config xml:lang

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, config

Здравствуйте!

при трансформации

```
<md:OrganizationName xml:lang="ru" xdt:Transform="Replace">Организация</md:OrganizationName>
```

на выходе получаю

```
<md:OrganizationName d5p1:lang="ru" xmlns:d5p1="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">Организация</md:OrganizationName>
```

Как мне получить конкретно

```
xml:lang="ru"
```

Comment: Как и с помощью чего выполняется трансформация?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017, создал отдельную конфигурацию, нажимаю опубликовать в папку

Comment: А почему вас это расстраивает? Разметка-то эквивалентная получается в любом случае.

Comment: вот мне и интересно равны ли они